# How to move an image inside the imageview to the upper end of the imageView?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

I have an imageView with contentMode UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit. So it resizes the image without changing the aspect ratio. But the image inside the imageview is horizontally and vertically centred.

I don't want it to be vertically centred. How can I move this image to the upper end of imageview?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make a custom UIView in which you can have UIImage property (just like UIImageView has) and you need to over ride 'drawRect' method of UIView and draw the image at appropriate position using [image drawInRect:rect]; method, check the documentation you will find stuff about aspect ratio as well while drawing...

In UIImageView, image's x,y position can't be changed..